In Visual Studio, pressing tab in front of if does some weird autocomplete instead of inserting tab
I'm using Visual Studio 2010 because I'm working with old software and a plugin that doesn't work on newer versions of VS. I have a problem that I can usually work around but it's getting really annoying and I'd like to fix it.
Let's say I have some code that looks like this:
if(foo)
    {
        bar();
    }

The brackets are where they should be. I want to tab if(foo) over to where the brackets are. So I move the cursor in front of if(foo) and press tab. Then somehow for some reason instead of moving if(foo) over by a tab, I get this monstrosity:
if (true)
{

}(foo)
    {
        bar();
    }

How do I make tab insert a tab, even if it's in front of if?
